# In Storybook how can you display the full source of a component in the "Show code" area of a story doc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, storybook

Right now in my team we are using Storybook v6 and the `@storybook/addon-docs` package in order to generate documentation for components.

In order to keep the `.stories.mdx` files small we write the story "showcase" components separately and then import them in the `.stories.mdx` files.

For example

```
// showcase/HugeComponentShowcase.jsx

import SomeComponent from 'components/SomeComponent';

export default function HugeComponentShowcase() {
  return <div>
    <p>This is a huge component showcase using SomeComponent</p>
    <SomeComponent propA propB propC/>
    <SomeComponent propB />
  </div>
}
```

```
// SomeComponent.stories.mdx

import { Meta, Story, Preview, Props } from '@storybook/addon-docs';
import HugeComponentShowcase from 'showcase/HugeComponentShowcase'; 

<Preview >
  <Story name="Generic component" >
    <HugeComponentShowcase />
  </Story>
</Preview>
```

This will result in this when you want to display the code of the showcase:

[image]

However what I want to be able to see there is:

```
<div>
  <p>This is a huge component showcase using SomeComponent</p>
  <SomeComponent propA propB propC/>
  <SomeComponent propB />
</div>
```

or at least the whole function body of `HugeComponentShowcase`.

I have tried adding this  to the `Story` component

```
<Preview >
  <Story name="Generic component" parameters={{ docs: {source: { code: HugeComponentShowcase, } }}}>
    <HugeComponentShowcase />
  </Story>
</Preview>
```

But this ends up showing the compiled code of the component and not the original JSX code.

Comment: Does this help? https://blog.krawaller.se/posts/implementing-a-source-code-view-in-storybook/

Comment: Hm, that's definitely one way to do it. It's not solving exactly the same issue but it gives an idea of how my issue can be tackled. I was hoping there was some baked-in way to achieve the desired result without having to write a webpack loader, but as I said, that's one way to do it, if there is no other option :)

Comment: Storybook tends to focus on using the components, not the code of the components themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The only I've found to show the desired code on storybook, when using .mdx files it's by using the `<Canvas mdxSource={'whatever you want to display'} ></Canvas>`

Comment: `mdxSource` is deprecated in later versions, so use `<Canvas source={{ code: 'whatever you want to display' }} />` instead.